# Why is Jetpack Compose using the old state in the onTap event

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm new with Kotlin and Jetpack Compose, and I have an issue in my Android app. When I run the code below, I can press the "Increase" button, and the Canvas shows the increased number. However, in the `pointerInput` `onTap` event, the number is always 1. Only when I force a recomposition by rotating the device, the new number is used.

It seems as if the state is used when it was first composited instead of the current state. How can I use the most recent state in the `onTap` event?

Some background: I use the Canvas to draw a grid with a dynamic number of columns and rows. The number in my example determines the number of columns or rows. In the `onTap` event I want to calculate which cell was clicked, to raise my own `onCellTap` event. I do this by using the formula to calculate the position of the cells used in `onDraw`, but in reverse. This all works fine, until a column or row is added dynamically, because I can't calculate with the "old" column count.

Instead of the `mutableIntStateOf` in this example, I use a `ViewModel` in my app. I removed this from the example for simplicity, I hope this does not matter.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun TopLevelComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var number by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Column {
        TestCanvasComposable(number)
        Button(onClick = {

            number += 1

        }) {
            Text(
                text = "Increase",
                modifier = modifier
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestCanvasComposable(
    number: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    Canvas(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(30.dp)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onTap = {
                    // This does not show the correct number:
                    Log.i("Test", "The number is $number")
                }
            )
        }, onDraw = {
        drawRect(Color.Yellow, Offset.Zero, this.size)

        drawText(
            textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
            text = buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(ParagraphStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Start)) {
                    // This works perfectly:
                    append("The number is: $number")
                }
            }
        )
    }
    )
}
```

I tried to remove the `TestCanvasComposable` Composable, and just put the Canvas code in the `TopLevelComposable`. After this change it works fine. But I'd like to keep them apart for potential re-use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are losing the state because when `@Composable` recomposes it resets the value of the number.

You can use `rememberUpdatedState` to track changes in `number` and `remember` last updated number.

```
@Preview
@Composable
fun TopLevelComposable(modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {

    var number by rememberSaveable { mutableIntStateOf(0) }

    Column (modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()){
        TestCanvasComposable(number)
        Button(onClick = {

            number += 1

        }) {
            Text(
                text = "Increase",
                modifier = modifier
            )
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun TestCanvasComposable(
    number: Int,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier
) {
    val num by rememberUpdatedState(newValue = number)
    val textMeasurer = rememberTextMeasurer()
    Canvas(modifier = modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(30.dp)
        .pointerInput(Unit) {
            detectTapGestures(
                onTap = {
                    // This does not show the correct number:
                    Log.i("Test", "The number is $num")
                }
            )
        }, onDraw = {
        drawRect(Color.Yellow, Offset.Zero, this.size)

        drawText(
            textMeasurer = textMeasurer,
            text = buildAnnotatedString {
                withStyle(ParagraphStyle(textAlign = TextAlign.Start)) {
                    // This works perfectly:
                    append("The number is: $num")
                }
            }
        )
    }
    )
}
```

It's working Check this code

Comment: rememberUpdatedState should be used when parameters or values computed during composition are referenced by a long-lived lambda or object expression. Recomposition will update the resulting State without recreating the long-lived lambda or object, allowing that object to persist without cancelling and resubscribing, or relaunching a long-lived operation that may be expensive or prohibitive to recreate and restart.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had expected a very complex solution, but there is a nice built in function for exactly my problem.